# Error reading raster tiles into R

Tags: r

I'm getting an error when merging raster tiles inside a custom function.  The following code works every time:

```
files = list.files("data_folder/")
tiles = list()
for(f in files) tiles = c(tiles, list(raster(readGDAL(paste0(dir,f)), layer=1, values=T)))
ras = do.call(merge, tiles)
```

But when I try to run this inside a function:

```
read_and_merge_rasters = function(dir){
  files = list.files(dir)
  tiles = list()
  for(f in files) tiles = c(tiles, list(raster(readGDAL(paste0(dir,f)), layer=1, values=T)))
  return(do.call(merge, tiles))
}
```

.. it reads the files in ok (confirmed by print report) but then fails with the error: `Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("RasterLayer", package = "raster")" to a data.frame`

I can't think where/why `as.data.frame` is being called.  Any idea why this is happening?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: No reproducible example, so I'd just suggest doing `debug(read_and_merge_rasters)`, calling that function, and then stepping through to the point where the error is thrown. From that point, examine the objects, try alternatives, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach (not tested, since you didn't not provide a reproductible example).

```
read_and_merge_rasters <- function(dir) {
    library(raster)
    files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
    tiles <- lapply(files, raster)
    do.call(merge, tiles)
}
```

You also have check that your differents raster in your directory are comparable (extent, origin and resolution).

Comment: It is fully reproducible if you apply it to any folder containing only geotiff tiles - e.g. one of [these](http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm). Will try your suggestion out.

Comment: The line is actually `lapply(files, function(i){ raster(readGDAL(paste0(dir,i)), layer=1, values=T) })`.  The code now mysteriously works, which is confusing as lapply only replaces part of the code that was working ok (but less elegantly). Hey ho.

Comment: Happy it works. Can you explain me why `raster(readGDAL(dir))` instead of `raster(dir)` ?

Comment: Hmmm it initially didn't work with raster but then did with readGDAL.  I suspect I have something else making my system temperamental.

Comment: Examples should be reproducible and self-contained: that is, the data should bre included (generated or example data that comes with an R package)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple merge functions. do.call will tend to send it to merge for data.frames unless you set the names of the first two arguments:

```
tiles <- lapply(files, raster)
names(tiles)[1:2] <- c('x', 'y')  
x <- do.call(merge, tiles)
```